# Oracle: Invalid number error on join between varchar columns

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a procedure that contains a very lengthy query. One particular join is giving me an 'ORA-01722: invalid number' error when I run the procedure. This is the join:

```
from adv.hr_giving_ag_cash g
left join aga_allocation_handling ah on ah.allocation_code = g.alloc_code
```

If I comment out the join line, the error goes away. There are a couple of puzzling things about this:

- Both the fields I'm joining on (ah.allocation_code and g.alloc_code) are varchar types, and have no null or empty rows. So there's no point at which a number would be involved.
- If I copy the query out of the procedure and execute it by itself, the error does not occur.

Also, nothing is selected from the aga_allocation_handling table. Eventually I will use it in the where clause, but for now that is commented out.

I'm at a loss as to how to even begin debugging this. Anyone have any ideas for me? Thanks!

Comment: The fact the query works if run outside a procedure should be a clue the problem may come from around, not from inside the query. Just 2 lines does not make your question a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: A result of a standalone query should be fetched in full (so I use CTAS or `select max(col1), ..., max(colN) from (<your query>)` to ensure this). Otherwise it will return top N rows that may or may not have the issue in the data. What if you explicitly cast both the columns to strings: `to_char(ah.allocation_code) = to_char(g.alloc_code)`?

Comment: As a debugging technique: create intermediary table with a result of your query and `g.alloc_code` added to the output. Then write a PL/SQL loop over the **sorted** intermadiary table with a `left join` to `aga_allocation_handling` printing the number of fetched rows (the row content does not matter here). It will provide you an ordinal position of the failed row which you may validate manually

Comment: @astentx I have tried adding to_char to both columns, I still get the error. I see your point about the query only returning the top N rows, I'll check whether the error occurs when all rows are fetched.

Comment: What do you do with the query results in the procedure - does that fetch or iterate over all rows, or only some? Adding the join could affect the orders results are returned, and/or exclude some so you hit problematic data earlier. And might either of the tables in that join actually be a view, which does some numeric conversion?

Comment: As my guess, your issue is not cause by that particular join. I think that join will only change your query result, which could lead to other comparison expressions/type cast become invalid (for example, NULL data value)

Comment: Like others have commented, please paste your entire SQL statement, including any insert/update/delete/merge line if it's actually part of DML.

Comment: @PaulW My query is way too long. I tried to post the whole thing just now, but it's 98,000 characters just for the query, not to mention the rest of the procedure.

Comment: @AlexPoole The query is in a cursor. In the body of the procedure, I iterate over all of the rows in the output and insert the rows into a table.

Comment: No-one is going to debug your entire query and procedure if it's that big. You need to break it down to a [mre] - doing so may well show you where the issue is. Did you establish if you get the error running the query and getting all of the results standalone? And are you sure the error is from the query, not from the insert?

Comment: You need to determine for certain where the error is occurring. While it may be in the join you identified, it may also be in how you are handling any column(s) you are selecting from that table in your SELECT clause or in some parent query block. It could also be something you are doing to those columns in PL/SQL in your loop. Since this is embedded in PL/SQL, you should be getting a full error stack. Use that to identify the line number on which the error is being thrown. If it's the first line of the SQL (or the OPEN if its an explicit cursor), then it's in the SQL. But it might be outside.

Comment: I will put something in an answer that isn't yet a full answer but I can't format code in a comment.

Comment: You say it's a very big query. Are there any other joins on either `ah.allocation_code` or `g.alloc_code`? You might have something else causing an implicit type conversion. Is only one schema involved?

Answer (score 0):

Find out for sure where your error is. You need an error backtrace. This is usually provided for you when an exception is raised to the caller, but you may be trapping it and not seeing the full stack. Try emitting it manually so you can debug, like this:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cur_whatever IS
  SELECT ... ;
BEGIN
  /* open your cursor, fetch through it, etc.. */
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(NVL(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace,SQLERRM));
    dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_stack);
    dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_call_stack);
END;
```

The error backtrace is the most important one. Use it to locate the correct line number in you code where the exception is thrown. If it's somewhere in PL/SQL, it should be easy to identify the problem. If it reports the starting line number of your SQL (or OPEN cursor call), then the problem is probably in the SQL itself.  If that's the case, pull the SQL out or into a new proc and deconstruct it until you identify the problem.

If the error is determined to be in the SQL and you can successfully run the SQL (to completion, not just until you start to see rows return) outside the procedure, make sure:

1. All bind variables are replaced with correct values
2. You are running as the same user that owns the procedure (to eliminate the possibility that you have different objects by the same name that you may be hitting)
3. The execution plan is the same outside as it is inside the proc. You'll need to get it from `dbms_plan.display_cursor([sql_id])` for the one that runs inside the proc. Hopefully it parsed successfully so it has a plan. Compare with your standalone version (`EXPLAIN PLAN FOR`... then `dbms_plan.display`). If the join order is different, that can actually cause a numeric error to come or go based on what internal conversion functions need to be applied to specific data that may or may not yet be filtered out by subsequent joins. Try to force the original join order with hints until you get it to match, see if you can reproduce the error.

These are just some debugging ideas to start with.

Comment: As you suggested it might, the backtrace points to the start of the sql. Here is a related question. You said to run the query in full to see if it completes. The query returns ~10 million rows, each row having a lot of columns. When I try to make PLSQL fetch all rows, the application crashes. Is there another way to test the full execution of the query without making my client crash?

Comment: yes, make it a CTAS (create table as select), dumping the results to a new table.

Answer (score -1):

Please see which column is of which data type.
To see that:

```
select *
from user_tab_columns tc
where table_name in (upper('hr_giving_ag_cash'),upper('aga_allocation_handling')) and
  column_name in (upper('allocation_code'),upper('alloc_code'))
```

Most likely you are comparing a number column to a varchar2 column. So, seeing what the select above return apply to_char() to the number column and this should solve the error. Although, I think there is something fundamentally wrong in the database design if you have to compare a number column with a varchar2 column. Generally you should compare

Comment: I clearly stated in my question that both columns are type varchar2.